# How to convert Wikipedia wikitable to Python Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, wiki, wikipedia

In Wikipedia, you can find some interesting data to be sorted, filtered, ...

Here is a sample of a wikitable

```
{| class="wikitable sortable"
|-
! Model !! Mhash/s !! Mhash/J !! Watts !! Clock !! SP !! Comment
|-
| ION || 1.8 || 0.067 || 27 ||  || 16 || poclbm;  power consumption incl. CPU
|-
| 8200 mGPU || 1.2 || || || 1200 || 16 || 128 MB shared memory, "poclbm -w 128 -f 0"
|-
| 8400 GS || 2.3 || || ||  ||  || "poclbm -w 128"
|-
|}
```

I'm looking for a way to import such data to a Python Pandas DataFrame

Comment: According to this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe a DataFrame can be constructed from one of these: Dict of 1D ndarrays, lists, dicts, or Series;
2-D numpy.ndarray;
Structured or record ndarray;
A Series;
Another DataFrame. The simplest is a dict of list/dict, but it is not apparent how your data can be coerced this way. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a solution using [py-wikimarkup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-wikimarkup/) and [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery/) to extract all tables as pandas DataFrames from a wikimarkup string, ignoring non-table content.

```
import wikimarkup
import pandas as pd
from pyquery import PyQuery

def get_tables(wiki):
    html = PyQuery(wikimarkup.parse(wiki))
    frames = []
    for table in html('table'):
        data = [[x.text.strip() for x in row]
                for row in table.getchildren()]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
        frames.append(df)
    return frames
```

Given the following input,

```
wiki = """
=Title=

Description.

{| class="wikitable sortable"
|-
! Model !! Mhash/s !! Mhash/J !! Watts !! Clock !! SP !! Comment
|-
| ION || 1.8 || 0.067 || 27 ||  || 16 || poclbm;  power consumption incl. CPU
|-
| 8200 mGPU || 1.2 || || || 1200 || 16 || 128 MB shared memory, "poclbm -w 128 -f 0"
|-
| 8400 GS || 2.3 || || || || || "poclbm -w 128"
|-
|}

{| class="wikitable sortable"
|-
! A !! B !! C
|-
| 0
| 1
| 2
|-
| 3
| 4
| 5
|}
"""
```

`get_tables` returns the following DataFrames.

```
       Model Mhash/s Mhash/J Watts Clock  SP                                     Comment
0        ION     1.8   0.067    27        16        poclbm;  power consumption incl. CPU
1  8200 mGPU     1.2                1200  16  128 MB shared memory, "poclbm -w 128 -f 0"
2    8400 GS     2.3                                                     "poclbm -w 128"
```

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use pandas directly. Something like this...

`pandas.read_html(url, attrs={"class": "wikitable"})`

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` to do some preprocess, and then use `read_csv` to convert it to a `DataFrame`:

```
table = """{| class="wikitable sortable"
|-
! Model !! Mhash/s !! Mhash/J !! Watts !! Clock !! SP !! Comment
|-
| ION || 1.8 || 0.067 || 27 ||  || 16 || poclbm;  power consumption incl. CPU
|-
| 8200 mGPU || 1.2 || || || 1200 || 16 || 128 MB shared memory, "poclbm -w 128 -f 0"
|-
| 8400 GS || 2.3 || || ||  ||  || "poclbm -w 128"
|-
|}"""

data = StringIO(re.sub("^\|.|^!.", "", table.replace("|-\n", ""), flags=re.MULTILINE))
df = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter="\|\||!!", skiprows=1)
```

output:

```
       Model    Mhash/s   Mhash/J   Watts   Clock    SP                                       Comment
0        ION         1.8    0.067      27            16          poclbm;  power consumption incl. CPU
1  8200 mGPU         1.2                     1200    16    128 MB shared memory, "poclbm -w 128 -f 0"
2    8400 GS         2.3                                                              "poclbm -w 128"
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited - complete answer below. I don't have Panda installed, so let me know if this works for you.

```
from pandas import *

wikitable = '''
{| class="wikitable sortable"
|-
! Model !! Mhash/s !! Mhash/J !! Watts !! Clock !! SP !! Comment
|-
| ION || 1.8 || 0.067 || 27 ||  || 16 || poclbm;  power consumption incl. CPU
|-
| 8200 mGPU || 1.2 || || || 1200 || 16 || 128 MB shared memory, "poclbm -w 128 -f 0"
|-
| 8400 GS || 2.3 || || ||  ||  || "poclbm -w 128"
|-
|}'''
rows = wikitable.split('|-')
header = []
table = []
for i in rows:
     line = i.strip()
     if line.startswith('!'):
         header = line.split('!!')
     elif line.startswith('|') and line.strip() != '|}':
         table.append(line[2:].split('||'))

data = {}
for i in range(len(header) - 1):
    col = []
    for row in table:
        col.append(row[i])
    data[header[i]] = col

print(data)

df = DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Ok, I just looked at the Panda docs (should have done that first), and I see exactly what you need now. Give me five minutes and I'll have a perfect example.